# .htaccess rewrite proxy with query params

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can some regex/htaccess wizard help? I'm looking for the rewrite rule that will

- support sub domains
- act via proxy (not a 301)
- pass along any number of query parameters (if present)

Such that, this proxies to that:

- www.domain.com -> www.otherdomain.com
- dev.domain.com -> dev.otherdomain.com
- www.domain.com?thing=123 -> www.otherdomain.com?thing=123
- dev.domain.com?thing=123&otherthing=abc ->
  dev.otherdomain.com?thing=123&otherthing=abc

*hugs*

Comment: Do you have `mod_proxy` enabled on `www.domain.com` and on `dev.domain.com`?

Comment: We have other proxy rules working. The DNS for domain resolves to the IP for otherdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming `mod_proxy` is enabled on `www.domain.com` and on `dev.domain.com` and both domains are using same DOCUMENT_ROOT**

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://otherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.otherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L,NE]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will be **automatically carried over** to the new destinations.

Comment: Oooh, looks promising. There is more than just www & dev (there's qa and staging as well) Generic regex for anything before the first . ?

Comment: I'm getting some weirdness. Still looking into it (getting 502 bad gateway).

Comment: When I use this rule (adding /subfolder/ to otherdomain) at this tester: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it seems to work, but query params don't seem to get passed through...

Comment: That site is not very reliable for testing mod_rewrite rules. I have tested same rule on my host again they are working fine and pass query string also.

Comment: Marked as answer, though, we have some other things at play preventing me from verifying this implementation.

Comment: Thanks for that. If you into any issues implementing it just leave a comment here.